# Are there any partial order comonads?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, monads

A comonad is a triple $(F,\mu, \eta)$.

$$F: C \rightarrow C$$

F is an endofunctor on some category $C$.

$\mu$ is a natural transformation such that,

$$\mu: F  \rightarrow F \cdot F$$

$\eta$ is a natural transformation such that,

$$\eta : F \rightarrow 1_C$$

Where $1_C$ is the identity functor on $C$.

I am interested in any monad where the functor $F$ maps an object to some well defined partial order on that object.  The reason I am saying object instead of Set is that, while I am interested in comonads on Set, I am open to other ordered structures if they don't happen to be on Set.  An example could be a functor that takes a set to the set of all partial orders on that set.

Do such comonads exist?

Comment: Any adjunction $G \dashv H$ induces a comonad $F=HG$ on the target of $H$. Then you can find adjunctions where $H$ takes values in a category whose objects are partial orders. Does that work for you?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am not sure I understand.  Perhaps an example would help

Comment: I added an example in an answer.

Comment: As a suggestion: it is usually a good idea to leave the question open for at least one day or two so that you can get a wider variety of answers and hopefully the community will upvote the better ones.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am going to reopen the question as you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Any adjunction $G \dashv H$ induces a comonad $F=HG$ on the target of $H$.

You can find adjunctions where $H$ takes values in a category whose objects are partial orders. Does that work for you?

For example there is an adjunction $G\dashv H$ between
$$G=(L\mapsto {\rm{Sp}} L):\rm{Loc}\to\rm{Top}$$
(the functor taking a locale to its space of points) and
$$H=(X\mapsto \mathcal O_X):\rm{Top}\to\rm{Loc}$$
(the functor taking a topological space to its frame of open sets)
where $\rm Top$ is the category of topological spaces and continuous functions and $\rm{Loc}$ is the category of locales, whose objects are complete Heyting algebras and whose morphisms are $\bigwedge$-preserving monotone functions with a $\wedge$-preserving left adjoint.

Composing the functors, you get a comonad $F=HG:\rm{Loc}\to Loc$.